# Remember the administrator password on Windows

Tags: windows-7, administrator

sudo on linux remembers the entered password for five minutes, so that when it's invoked multiple times in a short time, I don't have to keep inputting the password. Can I do the same thing on Windows?

Comment: for one thing, on linux it remembers it only for the present shell. not for a newly opened another shell. But since its not the case with Windows where different GUI prompts appear, I would say with certainty that its not possible in Win.

Comment: Dear Mr. President of World, when/where are you getting a prompt for your password in Windows? Are you talking about UAC/Shell/Locking (Windows + L)?

Comment: @kobaltz: I'm talking about UAC, whenever I need admin rights.

Comment: Even linux does this. Each time you need to perform an action, software updates with gui and change network settings with gui, chances are, you will be asked for your root password twice.

Comment: "Dear Microsoft: When the domain administrator has turned around and left after an over-the-shoulder UAC elevation, I want to be able to run any arbitrary programs of my own choosing as administrator for the next five minutes without the administrator knowing and asking pesky questions such as why I want to install two video games and a tool I found on a porn site, that _honestly promises_ to clean my computer of malwares, on the company PC.  Yours sincerely, someone on a WWW page with a pseudonym."

Answer (score 0):

If you are a good boy and run as a Limited User account, then you just turn on Admin Approval mode for Admins and use Fast User Switching to hide the UAC prompts.

I recommend everyone do this actually.

Comment: This really isn't an option for anyone that actually has a need to install a program daily.

Comment: @Ramhound: How so? Your User account just sits idle while you hope into the admin account to install the program. Once it's done installing, it's accessible just like if you installed it any other way, unless you specifically want the program to be **unaccessible** to other users.